# Intellij opening .jar file instead of .java

Tags: intellij-idea, ide

I have a class A which extends from another class B. When I CTRL + LEFT_CLICK on class name B intelliJ shows me its jar instead of .java file. How can I fix that?

Comment: What do you mean, it shows you the jar file? It shows it's location on the project pane, maybe? Or does something else? Also, check your keymap in intelij's Preferences -> keymap (the "navigate" section)

Comment: I am a little bit new to this topic so sorry if this does not make a sense but also when the project is build and run it does not compile the source code of this class instead it reads all the definitions from jar file. So when I make any change to that class in the source code it has no effect on the program which is running because it is reading all the definitions from JAR file as I mentioned.

Comment: Where this class "B" comes from? If from the library, you need to add sources for this library (in [library configuration dialog](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/project-library-and-global-library-pages.html)).

Comment: @Andrey It is my class which I wrote. It does not come from the library. I have source codes etc. I can open that class (.java) and make changes but as I said it is not compiled in the result (the final .jar file after build is the same as it was before the changes) because it somehow does not know about the change in that class (I use gradle for building). And super weird thing is that even inteliJ - IDEA does not recognize this class (when I CTRL + LEFT_CLICK it will show me only jar file not the source code). It handles it only as .jar file but that class DOES exist in the source code.